# How to check if user is on trial period?

Tags: ios, deezer

My iOS app uses Deezer SDK to stream music.

Is there a way to check (through web APIs) if a user is in his/her trial period and is therefore able to stream music on demand through the SDKs?

As per the specifics in here (http://developers.deezer.com/guidelines#content-access) only Premium+ users have this capability. I can testify that also freemium users in their trial period can do that (having all the rights of a Premium+ user).

The problem is, I want to know in advance if a Deezer user will be able to stream music on demand encouraging the purchase of a Premium+ account if their trial period has expired:

- to check if they are already Premium+ users I can query http://api.deezer.com/user/me with their token and check the "status" property (2 means Platinum+)
- for the freemium users in their trial period the status, correctly, reports 0 (freemium user) so status is not a viable way, since they can still stream
- also calls to APIs user/me/options erroneously report "streaming: false" for a trial user (they can stream!)
- lastly, I could use "inscription date" and check if 30 days have passed since that day to see if they are still in their trial period, but what if the user has an extended trial period (those provided by purchasing new phones for example) or what if Deezer decide to change the duration or remove trial periods in the future without notice?

Comment: Unfortunately, as stated here http://developers.deezer.com/support, this is the place Deezer developers intend for this kind of questions

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for now to know if the user is in a trial period. The only node you can check is "streaming" on the endpoint "/user/me/options", which informs you about the user's stream level according to the subscribed offer, I'm sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately, as reported in my post - 3rd bullet point, the property "streaming" is "false" for freemium users during their trial period, and I can attest they can stream the track in fact.